# Java-Synchronized String result in interference

Tags: java

I am using a simple program where 2 threads are defined to simply count down from 10. I have a ThreadColor class simply to be able to color the 2 threads in different colors.
    package com.sherif;

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Countdown countdown = new Countdown();

    CountdownThread t1 = new CountdownThread(countdown);
    t1.setName("Thread 1");
    t1.start();

    CountdownThread t2 = new CountdownThread(countdown);
    t2.setName("Thread 2");
    t2.start();

    }
}

class Countdown {
private int i;
String color;

public void doCountdown() {
    switch (Thread.currentThread().getName()) {
        case "Thread 1":
            color = ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE;
            break;

        case "Thread 2":
            color = ThreadColor.ANSI_RED;
            break;

        default:
            color = ThreadColor.ANSI_CYAN;

    }

    synchronized (color) {
        for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(color + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "   i= " + i);
        }
      }
   }
}

class CountdownThread extends Thread {

private Countdown countdown;

public CountdownThread(Countdown countdown) {
    this.countdown = countdown;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    this.countdown.doCountdown();
    }
}
```

I am synchronizing the for loop that counts down to avoid interference using the color object. Although I am defining the color as an instance variable that both threads share it still creates interference.
However, when I use a different string it works just fine.
I know that I can use synchronized on (this), but I would like to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: Define "interference".

Comment: ^^^ and also show us the code that works fine when use a different string.

Comment: Each thread does not count down the whole 10 digits. Instead, they keep switching.

Comment: Why do you think they shouldn't?

Comment: Why do you switch on the thread name, rather than just injecting the color as a constructor parameter?

Comment: @BheshGurung
class Countdown {
    private int i;
    String y = "ss";
    public void doCountdown() {
        String color;
        switch (Thread.currentThread().getName()) {
            case "Thread 1":
                color = ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE;
                break;
            case "Thread 2":
                color = ThreadColor.ANSI_RED;
                break;
            default:
                color = ThreadColor.ANSI_CYAN;}
        synchronized (y) {
            for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
                **same as above
}
}
}
}

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, as per my understanding, the instance variable is stored in the heap where both threads would share. since I am synchronizing using color(defined as string) the lock is acquired by thread 1 and would not get released until finished looping. same as the code I just commented using a regular string

Comment: @AndyTurner I believe that's a nice idea. However, I am really looking to find out what is the problem with using color "in this scenario" that causes a race event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `color` field *value* is not protected by simply synchronizing on the field, because the assignment statements that change the value are not synchronized.

The only thing the `synchronized` block does, is ensure that both threads are not running *inside* the block at the same time, and that's only if the value of `color` is referring to the same object.

Even though thread 1 is already inside the block, doesn't stop thread 2 from changing the value of the `color` field.

Timeline of your code could be:

- Thread 1 sets `color = ThreadColor.ANSI_BLUE`.
- Thread 1 enters block, synchronized on `ANSI_BLUE` object, and starts printing.
- Thread 2 sets `color = ThreadColor.ANSI_RED`.
- Thread 2 enters block, synchronized on `ANSI_RED` object, and starts printing.

  As you can see, they are not even synchronizing on the same object, so both can be inside the `synchronized` block at the same time.
- Both treads continue printing in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It makes a lot of sense now